# Converting a Frege List to a Java Array

Tags: java, arrays, list, interop, frege

Suppose I have a small, somewhat redundant bridge function defined in Frege

```
listToArray :: (PrimitiveArrayElement α) => [α] -> JArray α
listToArray = arrayFromList
```

and some Java code that passes an already obtained `TList<Long>` to it

```
TList<Long> tl_results = ...
Long[] results = FregeStuffies.listToArray(IPrimitiveArrayElement_Long.it, Thunk.lazy(results));
```

Eclipse complains that the arguments passed to `FregeStuffies.listToArray` are not applicable to what it is

```
listToArray(PreludeArrays.CPrimitiveArrayElement<α[],α>, Lazy<PreludeBase.TList<α>>)
```

Am I passing in the wrong {context}/{instance of `PrimitiveArrayElement`}?

Comment: Is this related to java somehow?

Comment: Frege is "a Haskell for the JVM".
Here, Frege passes a Frege list to Java, which passes it back to Frege to be converted into a Java array, given some context.

Comment: @YassinHajaj strongly related to Java, yes. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primitive array types need some special treatment in Java which also inhibits full generic use in Frege.

The reason for this is that we can't have primitive types as generics yet in Java. When we have

```
 static<A> ... foo(A[] arg) { ... }
```

in Java, we cannot instantiate the type variable `A` with a primitive type like `int` or `long`.

What this means is that, as it stands, your `listToArray` function is not going to work for Frege types that are based on Java primitive types (it is said that such things will be supported in Java 10).

For arrays of primitive types, you need to know which type it is and then call the appropriate method, in your case:

```
PreludeArrays.IPrimitiveArrayElement_Long.arrayFromList
```

Note also that boxed primitive types are currently not explicitly supported by Frege. This is because those types are supported through Javas auto-boxing and auto-unboxing automatically.

If you really need an array of boxed `long`, you can define `java.lang.Long` as a native type, make it an instance of `ArrayElement` and provide explicit boxing and unboxing functions. Because `java.lang.Long` is a reference type, there are no restrictions in using it as array elements.

Comment: As a sort of side question, what's the Java class name for the `[]` type? That is, if is it possible to have an `IShow` for a list type, what would its name be?

Comment: The list type constructor is  `PreludeBase.TList`

Comment: But the instances internal name would be `IShow_[]`, which is mangled as `IShow_$lbrack$rbrack`

Comment: In addition, when you have a type name that is not a valid Java identifier, it will get mangled. For example `O'Brian` would be a valid type name in Frege, but not Java